# beginner node.js callback example

Tags: node.js, callback

I'm pretty novice in nodejs 
This is a very easy php example that I want to write in nodejs

```
$key='foo';
$inside= openthedoor($key);
if(!$inside){ //wrong key
   $key= getanewkey();//get a new key
   $inside= openthedoor($key);//open the door again
}
```

How can I do this callback in nodejs?
appologies for the stupid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that you can still write things synchronously in Node.js, but if `openthedoor()` did happen to require a callback function, this is what it'd look like:

```
var key = 'foo';
openthedoor(key, function(inside) {
  if (!inside) {
    key = getanewkey();
    openthedoor(key, function(inside) {
      // check if we're inside again
    });
  }
});
```

A callback function is a function that is called on completion of another function. In the example, you are passing this function:

```
var callback = function(inside) {
  if (!inside) {
    // do something else
  }
});
```

Into this function to be called when there is a result:

```
openthedoor(key, callback);
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried to follow the same concept to actually build this:
1- I try to get list of calendars list on google api 
2- if the token is refused I generate a new token
3- with the new token I make another call again to retrieve the data
http://snipt.org/Ahhgb6

it does get the new token but It doesn't get the calendar list. Where did I go wrong?